# Selenium not finding all the elements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Selenium can't find all the  tags in a webpage. It finds only one, but there are two, and I need those two to make my script work. This is the [link](https://www.pixiv.net/en/artworks/93333481). I tried using WebDriverWait, but it still returned me only one of the  tags. I tried searching for different divs, but I kept returning me only one. I think it has to do with some of the classes that the second div has, and the first one doesn't, but I am really stuck.

[Here's the HTML code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luaLj.png)

```
full_image_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sc-1qpw8k9-3')
full_image_link.click()

full_image_link_ = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-1qpw8k9-3')
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the api to retrieve the image links, no need to scrape:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.pixiv.net/ajax/illust/93333481/pages?lang=en').json()
image_links = [i['urls']['original'] for i in r['body']]
```

Result:

```
['https://i.pximg.net/img-original/img/2021/10/10/23/35/09/93333481_p0.jpg',
 'https://i.pximg.net/img-original/img/2021/10/10/23/35/09/93333481_p1.jpg']
```

Comment: it worked, but not as I wanted. With the link I provided, I need to click in the image, because when I do that, a hidden div will display the link to the full resolution of the image. And the problem is that Selenium can't find this div after I click. 

and how did you get this link with ajax?

Comment: Ok, I guess you need the `original` url. I've updated the answer. You can check the full json with `print(r)`. You can check the api calls by inspecting the [network activity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/)

Comment: thanks man, it worked perfectly! And it even cleaned my code. Thanks again.

and if you don't mind, can I ask you something about this API link? Like, I opened the network tab, but I can't find this link. I opened it in this link(https://www.pixiv.net/en/tags/Emilia/illustrations?s_mode=s_tag). Is that correct?

Comment: You're welcome. Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it solves your question. As for the other issue: [this](https://www.pixiv.net/ajax/search/illustrations/Emilia?word=Emilia&order=date_d&mode=all&p=1&s_mode=s_tag_full&type=illust_and_ugoira&lang=en) is the api link.